# HOWTO override properties from a custom WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, wpf-style, staticresource

I have below WPF UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myComponents.UI.TextBoxWithPlaceholder"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:pEp.UI"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:TextBoxWithPlaceholder}}"
          Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="myCustomTextBox"
                 Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Padding="5"
                 IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 TextChanged="CustomTextBox_TextChanged"
                 GotFocus="CustomTextBox_GotFocus"
                 LostFocus="CustomTextBox_LostFocus"
                 Margin="5"
                 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
        <TextBlock Name="myPlaceholderTextBlock"
                   IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                   Padding="5"
                   Text="{Binding Placeholder}" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Foreground="DarkGray"
                   Margin="5">
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Basically it is a TextBox with a placeholder.

Now from a WPF view I reuse this component by doing:

```
xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:myComponents.UI"
```

and then place it as a normal control:

```
<ui:TextBoxWithPlaceholder Name="myNewTextBox" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}"
                           Style="{StaticResource myTextBoxStyle}"
                           Placeholder="please, enter something here"/>
```

Now as you see above I set a custom style for it:

```
<Style x:Key="myTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ui:TextBoxWithPlaceholder}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now in my "myNewTextBox" control I am trying to override some inherited properties for the controls named myCustomTextBox and myPlaceholderTextBlock such as Margin, Padding, Background, Foreground, BorderBrush, etc. but I have tried above style and it is not working. Also I have tried:

```
<Style x:Key="myTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ui:TextBoxWithPlaceholder}">
    <Setter Property="{Binding Path=Margin, ElementName=myCustomTextBox}" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="{Binding Path=Padding, ElementName=myCustomTextBox}" Value="0" />

    <Setter Property="{Binding Path=Margin, ElementName=myPlaceholderTextBlock }" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="{Binding Path=Padding, ElementName=myPlaceholderTextBlock }" Value="0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=myCustomTextBox}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="{Binding Path=Foreground, ElementName=myCustomTextBox}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, ElementName=myCustomTextBox}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to set properties of the `myCustomTextBox` from view that consumes your `TextBoxWithPlaceholder` control, you should add [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/custom-dependency-properties?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) to the latter and bind to them in TextBoxWithPlaceholder.xaml and set them in the consuming view, e.g.:

```
<ui:TextBoxWithPlaceholder ....PlaceHolderMargin="10" />
```

**TextBoxWithPlaceholder.xaml:**

```
<TextBlock Name="myPlaceholderTextBlock"
           ...
           Margin="{Binding PlaceHolderMargin,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```

I am afraid you cannot refer to `ElementName=myPlaceholderTextBlock` from a [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) outside the `TextBoxWithPlaceholder` control so trying to do this in a `Style` that's defined in a consuming view won't work.

Comment: Yes, I did. It worked ;) thx.

Answer (score 0):

This is a task that cries out for a Custom control and Visual States instead of a `UserControl` with Triggers.  But if you must do this as a `UserControl` (and I don't blame you because that's a lot to learn at this stage) then here goes:

First of all, when you use `ElementName` it is supposed to refer to elements that the XAML processor has already seen, previously in the current UI being laid out.  Not elements inside the control being styled.  I don't see that  approach working.

If you want the `TextBox` and `TextBlock` inside a `TextBoxWithPlaceholder` to use the properties of that outer control, you could bind them to it, inside your control's XAML.  For example, to rewrite a small part of that binding the background.

```
<TextBox Name="myCustomTextBox"
         Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Background={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource.FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ui:TextBoxWithPlaceholder}, Path=Background}}"
```

But if you truly want that nested TextBox ("myCustomTextBox") to use a style with triggers and its own dedicated property values, then what you might try is creating a `Resources` section inside your style that itself contains implicit styles for the `TextBox` and `TextBlock`  Something like this

```
<Style x:Key="myTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ui:TextBoxWithPlaceholder}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!-- Implicit style for TextBox should only apply to TextBoxes inside a TextBoxWithPlaceholder -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                </Trigger>
            <Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>

</Style>
```